# Using Qt and c++ in developing a game

Tags: c++, qt, qml, game-engine, qgraphicsview

I Have been searching for hours for a solution to my problem.
I am trying to develop a game using Qt and c++, the game uses hexagonal tiles and it is a board game. I am pretty new to Qt, I was wondering if there was a way to take a picture of a board and map out the x,y co-ordinates of the hexagons (It is 64 hexagons in a large hexagon, 5 hexagons to a side) so that I can assign movable objects to the hexagons (Move a game piece from one hexagon to another).

I have had a look at Qgraphicsscene and Qgrapgicsview, But is there an easier way of going about the mapping of the board?

Pointing me in the right direction will be a great help..

Comment: With some basic math you can figure out the real coordinates of your hexagon centers. Since you didn't specifiy the coordinate system you use, we can't help you there. I'm also not sure if this is actually your question?

Comment: What about using OpenGL with Qt? There is some extra initial work but you can then have various coordinate systems and show the board using different 3D views.

Comment: taking a picture of a board your program generates probably isn't a good place to start

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use QML (Qt Meta Language or Qt Modeling Language)  which is declarative language like Java-script for designing rich user user interface of a program: both what it looks like, and how it behaves. You can use vector and raster images and it has many easy to use features which enable you to make fantastic animations. Most of Android Apps developed with Qt use QML.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: I started working on a demo of this.  I have it drawing the hexagons, and highlighting them when hovered.

https://github.com/peteristhegreat/Hexagons

(end of update)

You may want to consider using `QGraphicsView`.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/graphicsview.html

If you look at what a hexagon grid looks like, you can map the centers of each hexagon to a 2d, x-y coordinate plane pretty easily.

If you use a `QPolygon` or a `QGraphicsPolygonItem`, you can get going pretty quickly.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qgraphicspolygonitem.html#details

[image]

Looking at the image above, you just need to create a filter that only allows objects to land on your xy grid, where a hexagon center appears, but not anywhere else.

Hope that helps.